# Why is the number of children of the root_node growing in this tree generation algorithm?

Tags: python-3.x, tree

I'm writing an algorithm which creates a tree that contains n number of nodes with random (0..1) weights (a.k.a the value of the node). Simply a structure like

```
    root_node
    /      \
   *        *
  / \      / \
 *   *    *   *
```

I'm trying to figure out why instead of the tree structure like in the above image, it's actually the number of children nodes of the root_node which is growing upon each iteration, see my capitalized comment in the algorithm below.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, children=[]):
        self.val = val
        self.children = children


def create_random_weights_tree(tree_size):
    """
    Creates a balanced tree structure of `tree_size` elements; inits each node
    with a random value between 0 and 1, and returns the root_node of the tree.
    """
    root_node = Node(random.random())
    bottom_nodes = [root_node,]  # holds nodes located at bottom of the tree
    nodes_count = 1  # counts total number of nodes in the tree
    while nodes_count < tree_size:
        next_bottom_nodes = []
        # iterate through bottom tree nodes
        for node in bottom_nodes:
            print(node)
            if nodes_count + 2 > tree_size:
                # put in a last single node
                child = Node(random.random())
                node.children.append(child)
                next_bottom_nodes.append(child)
                nodes_count += 1
                break
            else:
                # add 2 children nodes
                children = [Node(random.random()), Node(random.random())]
                node.children.extend(children)
                next_bottom_nodes.extend(children)
                nodes_count += 2
            print(root_node)
            # WHY ARE THE  NUMBER OF CHILDREN OF THE ROOT NODE GROWING??
            print(len(root_node.children))
        bottom_nodes = next_bottom_nodes
    return root_node


root = create_random_weights_tree(10)
```

print statements output of the above code:

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f76675eb910>
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f76675eb910>
2
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f76675eb7f0>
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f76675eb910>
4
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f7651f3b880>
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f76675eb910>
6
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f7651118070>
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f76675eb910>
8
<__main__.Node object at 0x7f76511180d0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the default value that is assigned to the `children` parameter in the `Node` constructor.

In Python, such a default value is only evaluated *once*, not on every call of the constructor. As a consequence, all your calls to `Node` (which provide no second argument) will assign the *same* list to the `children` property. And so, every child that is added, is added to this *single* list, which you also see at `root_node.children` (but also the `children` property in every other node).

To fix your problem, use `None` as default value, and create the empty list within the constructor:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, children=None):
        self.val = val
        self.children = [] if children is None else children
```

Alternatively, you could create a copy of the argument:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, children=[]):
        self.val = val
        self.children = children[:]
```

But then the caller should realise that the list that they pass is not the one that gets assigned.